# S-shaped curve approximation of given values

Tags: functions

I have a problem choosing the right function for approximation of measured values of light, when opening a shutter (based on shutter step number): 
Step;Light
0;0
10;2.9
15;5.1
20;28.4
25;87.5
30;184.3
35;239.8
40;243.8
These values give an S-shaped curve, which I've tried approximating with sigmoid function. But the problems is that such approximation is far too ideal (symmetrical, the same curvature on both "ends").
So my question is, what type of function would best fit into such values (they're repeatable and taken as an average of multiple measurements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problems, you could consider a scaled logistic function
$$y=a+\frac{b-a}{1+\exp(c+dx)}$$ where $a$ is almost the smallest value and $b$ is almost the largest one.

For sure, the problem is to have "reasonable" starting guesses. If the data cover a sufficiently large range, in a preliminary step, you can estimate (by "eye") $a$ and $b$ and rewrite the model as $$z=\log \left(\frac{b-y}{y-a}\right)=c+d x$$ and use a linear regression for getting estimates of $c$ and $d$. Once this is done (in your case, I should use $a=0$, $b=250$), you are ready for starting the nonlinear regression with "reasonable" and consistent parameters.

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} \\
 a & +1.45424 & 2.734  \\
 b & +250.796 & 4.471 \\
 c & +8.85757 & 0.605 \\
 d & -0.32968 & 0.023\\
\end{array}$$

which gives (at least to me) a quite good fit $(R^2=0.999636)$ (as shown in the table below)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y & y_{calc} \\
 0 & 0 &1.49\\
 10 & 2.9 & 2.41\\
 15 & 5.1 & 6.34\\
 20 & 28.4& 24.93\\
 25 & 87.5 &88.92\\
 30 & 184.3 &185.34\\
 35 & 239.8 &234.82\\
 40 & 243.8& 247.55
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

When you have many data points and small errors, you can also estimate by "eye" parameters $c,d$ since the inflection point occurs at $x=-\frac c d$ and, at this point, the slope of the curve is just $\frac 14(a-b)d$.

Looking at your data, we can visually write $$-\frac c d=\frac {30-25}2=27.5 \qquad \frac 14(a-b)d=\frac {184.3-87.5}{30-25}$$ and using $a=0,b=250$, this gives $c=8.52,d=-0.31$ which, as you can see comparing to the final results given above, are very reasonable.

Finally, if you want to impose that the function be $0$ for $x=0$, eliminate parameter $a$ from the model and impose it as $a=-b e^{-c}$. This would not change much the results as shown below
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} \\
 b & +251.289 & 3.591 \\
 c & +8.68734 & 0.410 \\
 d & -0.32381 & 0.016\\
\end{array}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y & y_{calc} \\
 0 & 0 &0.00\\
 10 & 2.9 & 1.03\\
 15 & 5.1 & 5.30\\
 20 & 28.4& 24.78\\
 25 & 87.5 &89.47\\
 30 & 184.3 &185.02\\
 35 & 239.8 &234.64\\
 40 & 243.8& 247.81
\end{array}
\right)$$

The sum of squares of residuals changed from $58.07$ to $63.70$

Comment: Thank you for such precise answer.

Comment: Yoy are very welcome !

Comment: Claude, merci beaucoup! Could you provide info about where did the suggestions from your previous edit come from? I mean the slope equation and why I can eliminate a, imposing it with the equation with b and c? And one more thing - how was the b estimated in the last table?

Comment: @Tomasz. I just thought but I bet that these are already known properties. For forcing the equation, just compute the expression for $x=0$,set the result equal to $0$ and solve for $a$. Concerning $b$, same story as before.

Comment: To summarize what I've learned so far: (1) Initialize a = 0 and b slightly more than max. value (e.g. 250). (2) Calculate c and d using the equations for inflection point and the slope. (3) Now calculate a and b "more precisely" using the primary equation (for scaled logistic func.) and that's all? @Claude, I know that I'm using math so poorly, as with some kind of hammer, and I lack the flair you have. So thanks even more for your patience and help.

Comment: @Tomasz. This is correct. So, you can get estimates from which a nonlinear regression will adjust. The key point is that you start with **reasonable** and **consistent** guesses. Don't worry : flair just reflects that I am an old man ! I am glad if I have been of some help to you. Cheers